Unable to login with Firebase UI
I'm trying to use the starter code from Firebase UI for setting up google login (with redirect), but it doesn't seem to work.
After I click on sign in with google and select my account, onAuthStateChanged still says I'm logged out and doesn't show any console errors.
Demo website: https://sbrjt.github.io/auth/ (Github)
Am I doing something wrong? Or is it one of their many bugs?

Here's the js code I'm using:
const config = {...}
const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)  
const auth = firebase.auth(app)

auth.onAuthStateChanged((usr) => {
    if (usr) 
        console.log('Logged in')
    else
        console.log('Logged out')
})

// firebase ui authentication
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth)

ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
    signInOptions: [
        {
            provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            clientId: 'my-client-id'
        }
    ]
})

(And I've added the website as an authorized domain in firebase settings and as an authorised js origins in GCP credentials.)

"it fails" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

I'm not getting any errors in the console. (I saw some errors and warnings before but they don't seem to appear everytime). Can u please take a look at the demo site? @AlexMamo

Well, I ended up using react-google-one-tap-login. I had to modify the callback a bit.
